# Angular replaced "/" to "%2F" in URL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I have a `<a>` tag

```
<a [routerLink]='[{ outlets: { userDetail: ["user/" + user.id] } }]'>
     <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
</a>


<router-outlet name="userDetail"></router-outlet>
```

but finally this replaced to http://localhost:4200/users/(userDetail:user%2F1).

How I can change "%2F" to "/" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare without `+` and `/` signs and use `,`:

```
<a [routerLink]='[{ outlets: { userDetail: ['user', user.id] } }]'>
     <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
</a>
```

Comment: @SergeyScream I am glad to help you!:)